# Is there value in logging an Exception in the filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, ilogger

I just read [A New Pattern for Exception Logging](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/a-new-pattern-for-exception-logging.html) and if it's correct, doing this makes sense. But I find the state inside the Exception handler has the passed in parameters (which is all I log) and a `throw;` does throw with the full stack.

So am I missing something? What is the advantage of moving it to the filter?

I am not going to copy the blog article in full over as I feel that is wrong. But here's the key example code:

```
try
{
    Divide(13, 0);
}
catch (Exception e) when (False(() => _logger.LogError(e, "Unexpected error.")))
{
    throw;
}
```

And here's the key point he makes:

> When an exception is thrown, the runtime will search the stack for a
> matching handler. So the runtime walks up the stack looking at each
> catch block and evaluating whether it matches the exception (e.g., the
> exception type matches). When a matching handler is found, then the
> stack is unwound to that point and the catch block is executed.
>
> The important part of this behavior is that there are two distinct
> steps: find, then unwind.
>
> ...
>
> The key thing to keep in mind about exception filters is that because
> they hook into the “find” part of the process, this means they run
> where the exception is thrown, not where the exception is caught. This
> is a little mind-bendy at first, but it makes sense: exception filters
> are run before the stack is unwound.

Comment: The call stack attached to the exception object within the `catch` statement also has the information about where the exception was originally thrown, so I am not sure what his point is.

Comment: [StephenCleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) posts here often - so I wouldn't be surprised if he personally replies to this thread

Comment: @Dai Good point about performance - could be made into an answer.

Comment: My comment (about `catch`) was factually incorrect and I've deleted it to avoid confusing other visitors, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the stack and the stack trace - whether you still have access to the local variables at the site of the original exception.

Quoting from https://thomaslevesque.com/2015/06/21/exception-filters-in-c-6/:
The call stack is a piece of memory allocated to the thread, that contains information for each method call: return address, arguments, and local variables. The stack trace is just a string that contains the names of the methods currently on the call stack (and the location in those methods, if debug symbols are available).

A simple example you can do which may demonstrate the difference is to run your code and check where the debugger stops (disable any e.g. Visual Studio settings which will automatically break on any DivideByZeroException being thrown).  With the exception filter, it will stop inside the Divide method, and you can inspect the locals.  Without, you will not be able to see the inputs which caused the exception to be thrown.

This becomes particularly relevant if you are e.g. debugging a crash dump of some process - with the local variables set, working out the issue might be easy.  Without, all you have is the stack trace, and you are hoping that is enough.

The link you provide demonstrates the difference from a logging perspective - that the logging context (containing some useful info about the local variables in `Divide`) is gone once you reach the rethrow (if you don't use exception filters).

Comment: I do see a potential point that the call stack may not have been unwound yet when the filtering occurs (I don't know off the to of my head if this is factually correct or not), having the potential to access local variables deeper than the catching scope, for logging, but then how do you refer to such scopes from the logging logic?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError See the logging scopes mechanism described in https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/a-new-pattern-for-exception-logging.html.  I haven't seen it before, so can't give further details.